# Delete items with bad STI type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I inadvertently added a bad value to the `type` column. Now I get `ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound` errors whenever trying to get it from the database.

Is there a way to delete these items with a bad type?

Comment: What is the name of your base model and the bad STI value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the records through the base model and issue a delete all.

```
BaseModel.where(type: 'BadTypeClass').delete_all
```